# $P=[a_{ij}] $ be a $5\times 5$ matrix over $\mathbb C$ such that $a_{ij}=\frac{5}{2}$ for $i\ne j$ and otherwise $a_{ii}=b+\frac{5}{2}$ where $b>0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Question: Let $P=[a_{ij}] $ be a $5\times 5$ matrix over $\mathbb C$ such that $a_{ij}=\frac{5}{2}$ for $i\ne j$ and otherwise $a_{ii}=b+\frac{5}{2}$ where $b>0$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the largest and the smallest eigenvalue of $P$. If $\alpha+\beta=14.5$, then $b^5=\dots$

My Attempt: Using the given data our matrix will look like $P=\begin{bmatrix}b+\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}\\\frac{5}{2}&b+\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}\\\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&b+\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}\\\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&b+\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}\\\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&\frac{5}{2}&b+\frac{5}{2}\\\end{bmatrix}$.

The row sum is $b+\frac{25}{2}$, this is the largest eigenvalue by the Gershgorin Theorem. So we have $\beta=b+\frac{5}{2}, \alpha=2-b$. Now $Tr(A)=5b+\frac{25}{2}$ and $det(A)=b^5+\frac{15}{2}b^4+b^3$ (calculated with row-operations only).I thought I would be able to determine other eigenvalues   but there won't seem any way out from here. Am I missing something? The matrix is symmetric though. The question was asked in one of my exam. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$A = bI_5 + \frac{5}{2}vv^T,$$
where $v = (1,1,1,1,1)^T$. $vv^T$ is a rank one matrix with eigenvalues $$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \lambda_4 = 0,\, \lambda_5 = \|v\|_2^2 = 5.$$
It follows that $A$ has the eigenvalues
$$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \lambda_4 = b,\, \lambda_5 = b + \frac{25}{2}.$$
Largest plus smallest eigenvalue thus equals $2b + \frac{25}{2}$. Solving for $b$ yields $b = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

One easily checks that the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$  is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $5$ of multiplicity $1$, and $0$ of multiplicity $4$. Hence those of $P=\frac52M+bI$ are $\alpha=\frac{25}2+b$ and $\beta=b$ (btw, $\det(P)=\alpha\times\beta^4=b^5+\frac{25}2b^4$).

$14.5=\alpha+\beta=2b+\frac{25}2\implies b=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing my answer and edited it before discovering yours.